# Home vista retrieval of wireless network password

Tags: wireless-networking, windows-vista

I want to upgrade to a new commputer but I have lost the password for WIFI.
I have tried the network, status, wireless network, security option but the "show characters" option is grayed and only dots to see.
Also tried DOS netsh show profile xxxxxx key= clear but  key is not accepted and without only shows security as "present".
Other ideas?

Comment: Did you try : http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/wireless_key.html

Comment: Everything OK now.  WirelessKeyView does the trick!

Answer (score 1):

Try the following Wireless Key software:

http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/wireless_key.html